# Why can't Windows 11 read properly the SSD which I connected to my laptop using a USB connector?

Tags: ssd, external-hard-drive, windows-11, formatting

I wanted to wipe an SSD that was previously in a PC with Windows 11. I connected it via USB to my PC and Windows is telling me "A specified device does not exist". I checked it using "diskpart" with the "list disk" command (from the Windows desktop itself, in case it matters) and, indeed, the disk is not being detected. Both the cable and the SSD are in good condition.

Furthermore, the PC emits a beep sound every x seconds indicating a USB connection/disconnection (accompanying each connection with the mentioned error message), as if it were trying to read the disk over and over without success. The relevant SSD can be seen from the Disk Management, but I get the same error if I try to format it.

I insist that the SSD and the cable are in perfect condition: the SSD comes from a PC that I refurbished myself and removed to replace it with another one with more memory, and the cable has worked with other drives without issues in recent days.

Here is the information you have requested in the comments:

- Model: SA400S37/240G
- Disk Management screenshot: [disk management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5B3E.png)
- CrystalDiskInfo can't read SMART data because the disk isn't recognized
- Cable: [cable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVC9r.png)

What could be happening?

The comment from Harrymc makes me think that some device with built-in software is necessary to read from the SATA interface, correct? It's true that until today, I would format the disk to NTFS format before removing it from its original PC, so it could be read as a regular storage drive. Is it possible that the error is due to this? How do I fix it?

Comment: What model is this SSD ?

Comment: harrymc, the SSD is a 240 GB Kingston SSD, model SA400S37, as I can see on the label

Comment: Show screenshot disk management + try see if you can get SMART (using CrystalDiskInfo or something).

Comment: Did you try both cable and SSD on another computer? Which cable is it that converts SATA to USB, or are you using an enclosure (and which one)?

Comment: I am going to write everything in the question. Give me a moment

Comment: the following thread mentions some of the possible causes. Don't just go for the drivers, but read the whole thread: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/kingston-ssd-wrong-driver-issue/347edd1d-c565-4333-b750-5871630020a8

Comment: also, this tutorial might help: https://windowsreport.com/ssd-not-show-pc/

Comment: What does "Device Manager" show in "Computer Management"?  Right-click on My Computer and select "Manage" to bring up Computer Management.  Do you see a USB device getting installed and then uninstalled periodically?  Do you see any errors in the Windows System Event Logs?

Comment: The drive oddly has no backwards compatibility with SATA IO, if the cable you used actually was SATA II, instead of SATA III that would explain the reason the drive wasn’t mounted within Windows

Comment: @Ramhound `backwards compatibility with SATA IO` what does that even mean? what's "SATA IO" (given that referring to the International Organization would make no sense in this context)? Besides, the vendor even [explicitly](https://www.kingston.com/en/ssd/a400-solid-state-drive) states that it is backward compatible with SATA 2.0 (even when it should always be the case anyway, AFAIK).

Comment: @TomYan - No idea but the specifications document specifically says it’s incompatible with SATA II

Comment: I've tried everything and nothing has worked. Any other ideas?

Comment: If the adapter cable is a SATA 1 only adapter, and the drive does not support SATA 1, there is your problem. What is the model of the adapter cable, and does it specifically list support for SATA 2 or 3?

Comment: I don't know the model of the cable. I should buy a new cable and try it again, isn't it?